# Shared element transition with viewPager

Tags: android

I have problem with `sharedElementTransitions`. I have one `activity` with `fragment` - from this `fragment` I start new `activity` with `sharedElementTransitions`, inside this `activity` I start `fragment` and inside this `fragment` is `viewPager`, now when I call `setTransitionName` in this `fragment` everything works very well, but when I move it to `fragment` that is inside my `viewPager` and call it inside `onCreateView` there is no smooth enter animation, back animation is working as intended. I was quite sure this might be resolved using `postponeEnterTransition`, so in my `activity` with `fragment` with `viewPager` I am calling `postponeEnterTransition()` and in my fragment  `getActivity().startPostponedEnterTransition()` but it is still not working... Any ideas what might go wrong?

Answer (score 4):

```
// Postpone the shared element enter transition in onCreate()
postponeEnterTransition();

// after the layout and data is ready, invoke startPostponedEnterTransition() to start the enter transition animation
// for example: 
sharedElement.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
 new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onPreDraw() {
         sharedElement.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
         startPostponedEnterTransition();
         return true;
     }
});
```

Please refer to : http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/03/activity-postponed-shared-element-transitions-part3b.html for more details

Hope it will be helpful!

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.

Comment: What if I have multiple shared elements? I need to add preDrawListeners for all of them?